# Dynamic .APK from GooglePlay store / Android

Tags: android, dynamic-data, google-play

My issue is very related with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407019/dynamic-apk-in-android) question. I'm working in a app that must implement a very uncommon behavior and, in my current overview, I don't know if it is a possible implementation. The main sequence of my desired behavior is:

1. The user is navigating in a browser, that can be either Android's browser or a desktop/remote browser, in a webpage (let's say "http://somewebpage.com");
2. The user access my dynamic website, that has a button to redirect him to GooglePlay store;
3. The user downloads my Android app from GooglePlay;
4. When the app download finish, in the first open of the Adroid app, it has a reference to the first visited page in item 1 ("http://somewebpage.com").

So, how can I properly implement this? Does GooglePlay store provide a way to pass dynamic arguments to downloaded apps? Is it possible to pass a dynamic
configuration file coupled with the .apk in app download-time? I've already spent lots of time in this, but I'm still with no solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, the installer isn't nearly that sophisticated, sadly. I'd imagine what you need is to figure out a way for your webpage to leave some sort of value on the phone for the app to access, though browser cookies are stored in the app's sandbox so those won't work.

Comment: Hi Hydrangea. Thanks for the reply! I'm really helpless with this desired mechams. The ideal solution was to be able to make .apk dynamic. A secondary solution I'm taking in consideration is to make all of these proccessments through web (saving/accessing information via web-services), but it seens to take much time.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: try and get the browser history to find the last page on your site visited. See [Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#HISTORY_PROJECTION) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history).

Comment: Yeah it works, but can't implement all use-cases. It fits very well when user is in Android's browser, but fails when user is using a desktop/remote browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea...
You could manipulate the Google Analytics referrer params and read them yourself through a receiver with the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` action.
Never tried it...
What I did when I had to create a dynamic APK, is use a lot of tricks and manipulations (compiling, signing, etc. through scripts) to create the dynamic APK and it was downloaded directly from our website.